How to avoid overloading pre-amp with a low output load?
When I connect a typical voltage pre-amp's output to an oscilloscope with 1 MΩ internal impedance, I can see the output clearly.
When I switch the oscilloscope impedance to 50 Ω, I cannot see the output pulses anymore.
I suspect that the op-amp used in the pre-amp is not capable of driving a large current through a significant load.
How can I isolate my pre-amp from the impact of the next device in the chain so that it works fine with both small and large loads?
I guess this is a typical problem faced by many people.
Are there some typical solutions?
Thanks!
Edit:
I thought this is a typical problem, that's why I omitted a lot of details in my description. Please let me use my current project in hand to explain better what kind of solution I am looking for.
We've built a pre-amp to amplify signal from an avalanche photodiode, we also used a second stage to amplify and stretch the signal so that cheap digitizers can also get enough samples of the signal. We even added a voltage follower after the second stage.
However, as long as we connect the output of an op-amp (could be the one in the second stage or the one in the voltage follower) to an digitizer with 50 Ohm  input impedance, the signal is diminished.
As explained by @Edin, this is simply because the input impedance of the digitizer is too small compared to the output impedance of an op-amp. How do I solve this problem?

The typical solution is to have the second stage have a much higher input impedance than the first stage's output impedance.

Sure. But my question is what if the second stage has a small input impedance, for example, a digitizer with a 50 Ohm input impedance.

You can use a step-down transformer, but of course there will be much smaller amplitude on its output.

@Jing Then you make the first stage have an even lower output impedance, or insert an intermediary stage if you can't do that.

For analogue signals, typically you'd buffer the signal, with a "voltage follower", a unity-gain voltage amplifier:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Provide the op-amp with supplies a couple of volts beyond the expected signal potential range; I'm using supplies of +15V and −15V here, which will support an input signal swinging between to ±13V; for most op-amps.
A typical op-amp can drive loads of 2kΩ or greater, though there exist "power op-amps" which can output enough current for a 50Ω load. They tend to be expensive. To cut costs, you could employ a regular op-amp, and boost its drive capability with some additional discrete elements, which would have no trouble with a 50Ω load:

simulate this circuit
Those two transistors form a class AB "push-pull" stage, described here. It's two "emitter-followers" (also called a "common-collector" configuration) connected in such a way that one of them (Q1) is a current source, responsible for parts of the waveform where current is pushed downwards through the load during the positive parts of the signal, and the other (Q2) deals with pulling current in/upwards through the load when the output should be negative.
There are ICs designed specifically for this kind of application, having unity gain, but higher output current ability. Consider the Texas Instruments BUF634, which is a self-contained follower capable of well over 200mA of output current.
There are always caveats to consider, such as op-amp bandwidth and output slew-rate, but we would need a lot more information about the signal in question to be able to suggest something appropriate.
The above solutions are for analogue signals, having arbitrary potential, but you mentioned "pulses", suggesting your signal may be digital in nature, switching between only two distinct potentials. If that's the case then you would probably wouldn't use an op-amp.
There must be a thousand different digital buffers, each designed for different levels and frequency of source signal, and for different load conditions such as sinking vs. sourcing current. This next design is a typical interface between a digital signal of high source impedance (such as from a microcontroller), and a relay coil requiring significant current:

simulate this circuit
This takes a weak (high-impedance) 0V or 5V digital signal which is unable to provide the necessary current to operate the relay, and imposes 0V or 5V across the coil with as much current as it needs. It can be trivially simple because we are not concerned with the precision, as we would be for an analogue system. In general, though, such digital systems are often more complicated than this, being tailor-made for each specific application. I won't even try to enumerate the options.

Thank you very much for the solution! Could you please explain a bit more about your second circuit? It seems that the "voltage follower"'s output is used to open two transistors so that current from the power supply can flow around the outer loop. But how would that current mostly flow through the load resistor instead of Q2?

@Jing Those two transistors form a class AB "push-pull" stage, described here. It's two "emitter-followers" (also called a "common-collector" configuration) connected in such a way that  one of them (Q1) is a current source, responsible for parts of the waveform where current is pushed downwards through the load, during the positive half of the signal, and the other (Q2) deals with pulling current in/upwards through the load when the output should be negative.

@Jing The pair draw very little base current from the op-amp output, so the op-amp is is not overloaded, able to produce any potential, unrestrained. The transistors produce a copy of the base potential at their emitters, but are able to source/sink the necessary load current via the supply rails rather than the op-amp. Feedback loop encloses the op-amp and the transistors, so $V_{OUT}=V_{IN}$, exactly.

Thanks for the detailed explanation and the link! I missed the point that Q2 has to be negatively biased to be conductive. Q1 and Q2 work in turns, one push, one pull, and the current always flows through Rload. R1 is used to create bias between base and emitter.

Now the only question left is why a simple follower didn't work for me. As you explained, I should have used an op-amp that was powered by a wide rail and capable of driving large current through its output. A power op-amp is what I needed if I stick to the simple follower design. Is that right?

@Jing Yes, the simplest solution is definitely a power op-amp. It doesn't need to be too beefy; If the signal never exceeds 10V, for example, you need an op-amp able to source/sink a little over $\frac{10V}{50\Omega}=200mA$. Don't overlook power dissipation, though.

Simon, can a power op-amp perform beyond its power supply? Say if the max power of its power supply is 1 W, can the power op-amp supply more than 1 W temporarily? If not, the whole question becomes how to construct a power supply that can drive a surge of current.

@Jing, Conservation of energy means you can't get more energy out that you put in. You can store energy over some time, and release it all in a short burst, but this is a different problem, requiring a different, more complicated solution. Even a weak 9V PP3 battery can provide more than 1W, why is yours so weak? 1W into 50Ω requires 7V RMS, so your signal is larger than 7V? An op-amp can't output a voltage beyond its own supply potentials, which is a bigger issue, building a >1W supply is trivial.

@Jing Have a look at the BUF634. It's a self-contained output current boosted follower, designed for scenarios like yours.

Simon, I just use 1 W as an example. My signal is less than 1 V. We used 3.3 V battery. I worry about transient power supply, not the constant one. I think your idea of storing energy somewhere would solve the problem. In your class AB amplifier solution, if we add filters to the op-amp's V+/- legs, the capacitors in the filters should be able to release their stored energy in a short burst. What do you think?

Ah, the power op-amp you recommended costs about $20 at Mouser. It is acceptable. Thanks!

A pre-amp is usually just that: a PRE-amp, meaning it comes BEFORE the actual amplifier, and usually its job is to merely raise the input signal voltage, while often also raising the current and converting the typically very high input impedance to a much lower output impedance.
Since the job of a pre-amp is to provide a sufficiently large signal for an amp, its output impedance is only low enough to match the relatively high input impedance of an amp.
An amplifier's job then is to greatly increase the power of the signal, both voltage AND the current so that the signal's amplitude does not drop significantly when loaded with a low impedance.
In your particular case, the pre-amp output may have 10 kΩ output impedance, which loaded by 1 MΩ oscilloscope impedance reduces the signal amplitude by 10k/1010k or by less than 1%, practically nothing.
But when loaded with 50 Ω, then the signal amplitude is divided 10050/50 which is 201 times or by more than 99.5%, leaving you with less than 0.5% of the signal's full amplitude.
Below is a simple schematic representation of your pre-amp loaded with 1 MΩ oscilloscope input impedance:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
And below is a representation of your pre-amp loaded with a 50 Ω load:

simulate this circuit
A pre-amp is almost always followed by an AMPLIFIER or a BUFFER which has a high input impedance matched to the pre-amp's output impedance, and a low output impedance matched to, or lower than, the load impedance to keep the power or the amplitude of the signal at maximum possible.
An amplifier's or buffer's input impedance can be and often is higher than the output impedance of a pre-amp, while its output impedance can be and frequently is lower than the load impedance.
At low or audio frequencies, the exact impedance matching is not as important as it is at much higher frequencies where maximum POWER delivery is often more important than the maximum AMPLITUDE delivery.

Thank you for the explanation of the small signal with the 50 Ohm load. How do I know the output impedance of an op-amp is 10 kOhm though? Is that a typical value? I cannot find this value in some op-amp's data sheets, for example, this one: https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/LMH6629/datasheet. I thought it was very small.

@Jing Output impedance of an op-amp is not 10kΩ - that is the typical impedance of a pre-amplifier, but it could be more and is often less. It's not defined for op-amps because it depends on factors like the supply voltage and the feedback employed. Your op-amp in the link specifies its maximum output current of 250mA, which means at 2.5V supply voltage it is 2.5V/0.25A or at least about 10Ω if I'm correct, but that is only its DC impedance/resistance. Op-amp output impedance also depends on the amount of load current, the type of load and frequency of signal. That's why it's not defined.

Edin, thanks for the explanation! I understand now that we should consider the output impedance of the pre-amp instead of the op-amp alone. To keep the discussion simple, what would be the output impedance of a voltage follower built on LMH6629? Since very little current flows back through the feedback loop, the current goes through the load resistor is mostly from the op-amp output. Wouldn't the output impedance of this follower simply the internal impedance of the op-amp?

@Jing I would say so, but I would be cautious about it. In this case the 250mA is maximum output current, but that would probably apply only to DC current. Also, there could be an issue with linearity, meaning at such high current you would have distortion of the signal, and so on. I didn't delve much into impedance calculations, so I couldn't tell you all about it. There is a lot of information on the Internet, and a lot to learn and figure out.

Edin, that's my feeling as well. The op-amp cannot supply a surge of current, which demands very high power. I guess that's why we need a power op-amp for the voltage follower as suggested by Simon.

I wish I could accept two answers. You explained why I observed very small signal with a small load. Simon provided two good solutions. Thank you both!

@Jing You're right, I focused on the problem too much, instead of providing the solution(s).
